# Inheritance in go data structure

Tags: go

Is there a better way to achieve the inheritance in go? (In c# we use Abstract class and Interfaces to achieve similar behavior). Please refer below code to understand the problem.

I tried using interface in Go but I am unable to access the data fields of struct.

```
type Vehicle struct {
    Id          int
    Name        string
    VehicleType VehicleTypeBase
}

type VehicleTypeBase struct {
    Id     int
    Name   string
    Milage int
}

type VehicleTypeSedan struct {
    VehicleTypeBase
    IsABSEnabled bool
}

type VehicleTypeHatchback struct {
    VehicleTypeBase
    Is4WheelDriveEnabled bool
}

func main() {
    var veh Vehicle

    veh = Vehicle{
        Id:   1,
        Name: "Zeep Compass",
        VehicleType: VehicleTypeSedan{
            Id:           1,
            Name:         "Sedan",
            Milage:       13,
            IsABSEnabled: true,
        },
    }
}

// Above initialization gives error. Here, I would like to understand that how // to achieve inheritance using base class
// in Golang. Is there a way to solve this situation in Go??
```

The error message is:

> .\main.go:40:3: cannot use VehicleTypeSedan literal (type VehicleTypeSedan) as type VehicleTypeBase in field value

Comment: There's no inheritance in go. You can try using interfaces, but you'll have to expose the fields via getter methods.

Comment: You need to think about the problem differently, and given that this seems to be example code, it's hard to say what you actually need to do differently. But the key is: Go has no inheritance and no class hierarchy, *do not try to write Java/C# in Go, it will never work*. Write Go in Go; solve problems the Go way, not the way of any other language.

Answer (score 0):

Struct embedding is how go lang prefers. Composition is better than inheritance is the idea.

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

You should declare an interface for Vehicle and all the Vehicles implement that interface.

This is design level problem than just fixing the error. Since its not clear exactly how you are going to use and deal with Vehicles. I will make some assumptions.

By Embedding way should embed a reusable struct inside specific structs.

```
type VehicleTypeGeneral struct {
    Id     int
    Name   string
    Milage int
}

//Embed VehicleTypeGeneral
type VehicleTypeHatchback struct {
    VehicleTypeGeneral
    Is4WheelDriveEnabled bool
}
```

If we creates instance vh of `VehicleTypeHatchback` then we can access fields of `VehicleTypeHatchback` as well as embedded struct `VehicleTypeGeneral` like `vh.Is4WheelDriveEnabled` and `vh.VehicleTypeGeneral.Name`

If `VehicleTypeGeneral` implement interface like `Vehicle` interface then `VehicleTypeHatchback` also implements that. You can override by implementing the methods though.

I have added type check example in `processSpecificVehicle` function. However these things slow the execution. Instead try to use the approached mentioned in `processVehicle` and `processAbsVehicle`

Also the interfaces should not have to many methods. One or two are enough other wise it is violation of interface segregation principle. Keep the interfaces short and meaningful and design them from the prospective of consumer of interfaces.

**Complete example with certain assumptions:**

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Vehicle interface {
    GetId() int
    GetName() string
}

type AbsVehicle interface {
    IsAbsEnabled() bool   
}

type VehicleTypeGeneral struct {
    Id     int
    Name   string
    Milage int
}

func (v *VehicleTypeGeneral) GetId() int{
    return v.Id
}

func (v *VehicleTypeGeneral) GetName() string{
    return v.Name
}

type VehicleTypeSedan struct {
    VehicleTypeGeneral
    IsABSEnabled bool
}

func(vs *VehicleTypeSedan) IsAbsEnabled() bool {
    return vs.IsABSEnabled
}

type VehicleTypeHatchback struct {
    VehicleTypeGeneral
    Is4WheelDriveEnabled bool
}

func main() {
    println("Hello")

    var vehicle = VehicleTypeSedan{IsABSEnabled: true, VehicleTypeGeneral: VehicleTypeGeneral{Id:1001,Name:"Sedan 1", Milage:12}}

    processVehicle(&vehicle)
    processAbsVehicle(&vehicle)
    processSpecificVehicle(&vehicle)
    processSedan(&vehicle)
}

func processVehicle(vehicle Vehicle){
    println(vehicle.GetId())
    println(vehicle.GetName())  
}


func processAbsVehicle(vehicle AbsVehicle){
    println(vehicle.IsAbsEnabled())

}

func processSpecificVehicle(vehicle Vehicle){
    switch v := vehicle.(type) {
    case *VehicleTypeSedan:
        fmt.Printf("Its a sedan %v with ABS %v ", v.GetName(), v.IsAbsEnabled())
    case *VehicleTypeHatchback:
        fmt.Printf("Its a VehicleTypeHatchback %v", v.GetName())
    default:
        fmt.Printf("Its a Vehicle")
    }

}

func processSedan(vs *VehicleTypeSedan){
    println("\nprocess sedan")
    println(vs.VehicleTypeGeneral.Name)
    println(vs.IsABSEnabled)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijit! It seems to be working. However, I am wondering why Interface is not allowed to define a field. Putting the getters setters looks a workaround. Its more simpler in OOP language. I am not sure if there are better approach to solve this kind of problem. In real world scenario we will have more complex data structures. :-). Also I have gone through an issue in Golang (Github) which is similar in nature: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23796

Comment: I have added a func `processSpecificVehicle` that uses type checking however makes the execution little slow. For complex data struct embedding like in `VehicleTypeSedan` should be fine since you can directly access all the data (including embedded struct `VehicleTypeGeneral`) and you know that you have to operate on that specific struct

Comment: Added func processSedan, you can see that we can access directly the fields of  `VehicleTypeSedan` as well as embedded struct `VehicleTypeGeneral`.

Comment: Go tries to address problems in OOPs so in go lang try to embrace go lang principle of embedding over traditional inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

It's can work!

```golang
type Vehicle struct {                        
    Id          int
    Name        string
    VehicleType VehicleTypeInterface
}

type VehicleTypeInterface interface{}

type VehicleTypeBase struct {
    Id     int
    Name   string
    Milage int
}

type VehicleTypeSedan struct {
    VehicleTypeBase
    IsABSEnabled bool
}

type VehicleTypeHatchback struct {
    VehicleTypeBase
    Is4WheelDriveEnabled bool
}

func main() {
    var veh Vehicle

    veh = Vehicle{
        Id:   1,
        Name: "Zeep Compass",
        VehicleType: VehicleTypeSedan{
            VehicleTypeBase: VehicleTypeBase{
                Id:     3,
                Name:   "Sedan",
                Milage: 13,
            },
            IsABSEnabled: true,
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", veh)
}
```

Comment: By doing so, you throw all of the static checks and guarantees out the window. You won't be able to do anything with a VehicleType without a type switch or type assertion. Sometimes this is acceptable/recommended and sometimes it's the only way, but I feel that this is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @Sergio: Could you please give me some hints for type assertion using interface to solve this problem? I guess this is a common problem where ever we will have Type dependencies with actual domain model. In this example Vehicle has a type  field of VehicleType.